# Click NSOutlineView not redraw

Tags: cocoa, core-animation, nsoutlineview

I have a `NSOutlineView`.When I add core animation for its layer,for example fade in and out,I find that its cell view do not redraw when I click.However,when I remove the animation,the outline view becomes normal.so why this happen? And how can I solve this problem?

```
[_outlineview.layer addAnimation:tAnimation forKey:@"animateOpacity"];
```

update:

I add the animation to the superview of the outline view.The problem has been solved.But I don't know why.

Comment: Without code we have no idea except that you have a programming error.

Comment: Were you adding the animation differently before?

Comment: I mean now you say to the superview, meaning the scroll view ? Or calling the outline view's superview method to get the superview?

Comment: NO,not the scrollview ,I add the outline view to another NSView

Comment: When the animation stop delegate is called ,I remove all animations.